# python requests post json data

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I want to post JSON data by requests. I used Fiddler to inspect the data transmission. The data I want to post is below:

```
{'configList': [{'ccolumn': 'gender',
   'ctable': 'arc_mxdata_operator',
   'cvalue': '男',
   'formula': '包含',
   'integral': 1,
   'integralIfMissing': 0,
   'resultIfMissing': '10'},
  {'ccolumn': 'gender',
   'ctable': 'arc_mxdata_operator',
   'cvalue': '女',
   'formula': '包含',
   'integral': 0,
   'integralIfMissing': 0,
   'resultIfMissing': '10'}],
 'id': 'Sushifaker',
 'infoList': [{'info_formula': '<=', 'info_integral': 5, 'info_result': '30'}],
 'name': 'Submit2018-11-27-19-18-30',
 'ratio': None,
 'ratioMaxCount': None,
 'type': '10',
 'typeResultStatus': '10'}
```

I found this data is urlencoded when uploading. So I encode the data in python

```
data = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)
rs = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

The response in rs is failed. I can not post the data. But I found the correct data found in Fiddler is

```
name=Submit2018-11-27-19-18-30&id=999&ratio=&ratioMaxCount=&configList=%5B%7B%22ctable%22%3A%22arc_mxdata_operator%22%2C%22ccolumn%22%3A%22gender%22%2C%22formula%22%3A%22%E5%8C%85%E5%90%AB%22%2C%22cvalue%22%3A%22%E7%94%B7%22%2C%22integral%22%3A1%2C%22integralIfMissing%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22ctable%22%3A%22arc_mxdata_operator%22%2C%22ccolumn%22%3A%22gender%22%2C%22formula%22%3A%22%E5%8C%85%E5%90%AB%22%2C%22cvalue%22%3A%22%E5%A5%B3%22%2C%22integral%22%3A0%2C%22integralIfMissing%22%3A0%7D%5D&infoList=%5B%7B%22info_formula%22%3A%22%3C%3D%22%2C%22info_integral%22%3A5%2C%22info_result%22%3A%2230%22%7D%5D&type=10&typeResultStatus=10&ruleType=0
```

The difference between two data is `ratio=&ratioMaxCount=`, it's looks like a parameters in a url. I don't know why and how to get a correct data to post.

Update:
After reading doc from `urllib` and check the difference between two output. I have misused `quote` and `urlencode`.

Comment: Use empty string rather than `None`?

Comment: @GarrettKadillak It works. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `None` with `''`

That will solve it.

Comment: It's my fault. I am confused with `quote` and `urlencode`.  After replaceing None with '', it works.